# multiple executed statements in one condition? help please

Tags: java, if-statement

For if and else conditions, is there a way to put more than one statement to be executed for each condition?

**Example:**

```
if ( loan < 1000 )
    f = (loan * 100 / 1000);
    **System.out.println( "The loan amount is $" + loan );
    System.out.println( "The finance charge is $" + f );
    System.out.println( "The total cost is $" + (loan + f) );**
```

How can I format it so multiple conditions (bolded) is included in the condition?

Comment: Did you tried to read basic tutorial?! You need to wrap those statements within braces {}.

Comment: sorry guys :D I won't do this again

Comment: Nobody deserves rep for answering this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, enclose them in curly braces:

```
if ( loan < 1000 ) {
    f = (loan * 100 / 1000);
    System.out.println( "The loan amount is $" + loan );
    System.out.println( "The finance charge is $" + f );
    System.out.println( "The total cost is $" + (loan + f) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use braces around the lines you want to execute.

Answer (score 0):

You brackets `{}` :

```
if ( loan < 1000 ) {
    f = (loan * 100 / 1000);
    System.out.println( "The loan amount is $" + loan );
    System.out.println( "The finance charge is $" + f );
    System.out.println( "The total cost is $" + (loan + f) );
}
```

Everything inside the curly brackets would be executed if the condition of the `if` statement evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use curly braces (`{ }`) to specify a block:

```
if ( loan < 1000 ) { // Note the "{"
    f = (loan * 100 / 1000);
    System.out.println( "The loan amount is $" + loan );
    System.out.println( "The finance charge is $" + f );
    System.out.println( "The total cost is $" + (loan + f) );
} // Note the "}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( loan < 1000 ) {
    f = (loan * 100 / 1000);
    System.out.println( "The loan amount is $" + loan );
    System.out.println( "The finance charge is $" + f );
    System.out.println( "The total cost is $" + (loan + f) );
}
```